# Flutter develops Bluetooth, how to monitor the link status of the device in real time

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I use flutter_blue_plus. In the business, I successfully connect to the Bluetooth device. At this time, the mobile phone is away from the device, the Bluetooth is disconnected, and then close to the device, and the Bluetooth is automatically connected. At this time, how does my program get the device object again. A stupid way I use now is to start a timer and get the Bluetooth device connected to the mobile phone at an interval of 2s, and perform eigenvalue matching and other operations.

```
_timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
    if (_bluetoothIsConnected == false) {
        _getDevice();
    }
});

  void _getDevice() async {
    List<BluetoothDevice> bluetoothDevices = [];
    bluetoothDevices = await _flutterBlue.connectedDevices;
    if (bluetoothDevices.isEmpty) return;
    for (var device in bluetoothDevices) {
      if (device.name == _vehicleInfo!.imei || device.name == '000000000000000') {
        _device = device;
        if (!_bluetoothIsConnected) {
          _deviceConnect(false);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: tried [scanResults](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_blue/latest/flutter_blue/FlutterBlue/scanResults.html) ?